# Ipad Custom font doubts

Tags: ipad, fonts, uifont

I am developing a ipad application in ios4.3,i need to add manorama.ttf to my project.How to do this,please help me,i already saw many solution but i did'nt found "just add the key UIAppFonts as array to your Info.plist" any value UIAppFonts in my info.plist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a [tutorial](http://kgriff.posterous.com/45359635) that shows you how to use custom fonts.

Comment: [UIFont fontWithName:@"CloisterBlack" size:64.0] ,,where did i put this code?

Comment: UILabel and UITextView have a property "font". So you you use it: yourLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName.....]

Comment: but i didn't get my font.I add uifont in array that mention in tutoril.i am using 4.3 stimulator.

Comment: i want to display xml data in my text view with my custom font,the data displays in some other format,because unsupport of that font.